# How to access dynamic children components in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a `<Grid>` Component where `<Rows>`are added dynamically. As shown below

[image: Grid]

on click of `Add Menu Item` I push a `<Row>` component to the `<Grid>`

on click of `Save` I want to access the data inside all the `<Row>` components so far. I know we can access a single input using `refs` but is there a way to fetch the grid contents into a single array of objects in React.?

Comment: Sometime age I had interview task to build dynamic list with possibility to edit. If you wish you can check it and maybe it will help you with your task : https://github.com/uhlryk/egnyte-test

Comment: You can refer to my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941829/how-to-load-component-dynamically-in-reactjs/46188808#46188808

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looping over `this.props.children` in `<Grid>`? If `<Row>` exposes a getter method you should be able to access its content this way.