# Dynamically adding components in react

Tags: reactjs, components

I need to add components by rendering it in react:

```
<componentName ..... />
```

However, the name of component is not known and coming from a variable.
How I can render that?

Comment: Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941829/how-to-load-component-dynamically-in-reactjs/46188808#46188808

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a file that exports all the different components

```jsx
// Components.js
export Foo from './Foo'
export Bar from './Bar'
```

then import them all

```jsx
import * as Components from './Components'
```

then you can dynamically create them based on a variable/prop:

```jsx
render() {
  // this.props.type = 'Foo'
  // renders a Foo component
  const Component = Components[this.props.type];
  return Component && <Component />;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You will need to store references to the dynamic components:

```
import ComponentName from 'component-name'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.components = {
            'dynamic-component': ComponentName
        }
    }

    render() {
      // notice capitalization of the variable - this is important!
      const Name = this.components[this.props.componentName];

      return (
        <div>
          <Name />
        </div>
      )
    }
};

render(<App componentName={ 'dynamic-component' } />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

See the [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the official docs about it, missed that!

Answer (score 0):

```
Okay, for me this worked:

import {Hello} from 'ui-hello-world';

let components = {};

components['Hello'] = Hello;
export default components;
```

and then in my class:
import customComps from '.....json';
....
 let Component = Custom.default[customComps.componentName];

```
      return (
        <Component
```